# SSIS Script component: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssis, etl, script-component

I'm using a script component to upsert data to MongoDB. As MongoDB driver is not signed, and thus can't be added to GAC, I using the following method to load it at runtime from the known location where all needed reference DLL are saved:

```cs
private const string AssembyPath = @"C:\Users\acme\source\repos\import-members-and-optins\lib";
    
static ScriptMain()

{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    // retrieve just a name of this assembly
    var assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(AssembyPath, string.Format("{0}.dll", assemblyName));
    try
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{fullPath} not found", ex);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following exception, and I'm not even able to debug it, as it's happening before the task is able to run. It's like the handler is never executed. I have checked and my package is running in x86, so I should be able to debug it, but my handler is never hit. :-(

> Package Validation Error Error at Data Flow Task [Upsert Mongo [69]]:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'ScriptMain' threw an exception. ---> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.14.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.**    at ScriptMain..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at ScriptMain..ctor()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
> publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Why are you adding a driver to your project?  Drivers are install on the machine and get added to the Device Manager.  An application does a lookup in the installed device to get the driver, not the application.

Comment: Hi @jdweng I'm just adding a reference to MongoDB database driver, which is a standalone dll

Comment: Are you executing client or server code?  The connection to database should be in the server code.  Client should make a request to the server and the server handles the connection to the database.  The standalone dll is probably server code which on the first call uses a connection string to connect to the database.

Comment: Hi @jdweng This is an SSIS package running in my local machine used to import data to a MongoDB instance.

Comment: The SSIS script runs on the server not on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main issue is caused by **initiating variables globally** within the class which is called before the assembly resolver is fired.

Try not to initiate any variable within the `public class ScriptMain : UserComponent` class and mover them into the appropriate methods or int the `PreExecute` method.

Try changing your code to the following:

```cs
static ScriptMain()

{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string AssembyPath = @"C:\Users\acme\source\repos\import-members-and-optins\lib";
    // retrieve just a name of this assembly
    var assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(AssembyPath, string.Format("{0}.dll", assemblyName));
    try
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{fullPath} not found", ex);
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that no other variables are initiated globally.

#### Helpful resources

- [Assembly not found in SSIS Script Component- Random](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf91f8af-26c2-4980-8f91-3ba2fd3df4c1/assembly-not-found-in-ssis-script-component-random?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Loading external assemblies in SSIS script tasks](https://richardswinbank.net/ssis/loading_external_assemblies)
- [AssemblyResolve not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706794/assemblyresolve-not-fired)

Comment: Thanks, still wondering how could I miss this, there was a static filed initialized inline, once I moved it to static constructor right after handler initialization now it works fine.

Comment: @Oscar I faced the same issue previously,  and spent lot of time to solve it. It is very tricky.